# Найти первое слово строки

Tags: javascript

Получается задача в чём. Нужно найти первое слово строки, но при этом игнорируя запятые. точки и пробелы перед или после слова.

```js
var string = "Hallo, World";





function firstWord(str) {
    // returns the first word in a given text.
    var SpaceCode = str.indexOf(" ")
    if (str.indexOf === -1) {
        return str;
    } else if (str.charAt(0) === "," || str.charAt(0) === "" || str.charAt(0) === "." ) {
        return str.substr(1, SpaceCode);
    } else if(str.charAt(1) === ",") {
        return str.substr(0, SpaceCode);
    } else {
        return str.substr(0, SpaceCode);
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return 0;
}

console.log(firstWord(string));
```

Это мой код, немного криво написан. Но суть в чём он ищет первое слово, игнорирует перед словом точку но не игнорирует много торчек например если бы строка была такая `(firstWord("... and so on ..."), "and")` и почему-то не игнорирует пробел перед словом.

Comment: `str.charAt(0) === ""` всегда даст false

Comment: @Grundy Да я это понял, но как заставить тогда игнорировать пробел перед словом или даже пробелы?

Comment: во-первых, надо составить список символов, которые не могут быть внутри функции, во-вторых, пробежаться циклом по строке ища первый символ не из этого списка - это будет начало слова, потом пробежаться пока не будет конец строки или символ из списка - это конец слова. Ну и еще можно попробовать использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: @Grundy так хорошо, я почти всё понял. Условно я составил список, пускай это будут(запятые, пробелы и точки). Дальше я написал цикл корорый переберает полностью строку. НО как мне пробегаясь циклом по строке искать символ не из этого списка, который и будет первым словом?

Comment: например с помощью того же `.indexOf` проверять наличие текущего символа строки в массиве

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Термин "слово" в контексте регулярных выражений обозначает буквы + цифры + нижнее подчеркивание. Если вам нужно это, тогда:

```
var matches = '... some_long_word another word ...'.match(/(\w+)/);
var firstWord = matches[1];
```

Если только слова (русские + английские):

```
var matches = '... some_long_word another word ...'.match(/([a-zа-яё]+)/i);
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение с помощью регулярного выражение оно работает. Но у меня вопрос, возможно ли написать такую функцию что бы она выбтрала первое слово как это регулярное выражение. И насколько это будет рационально?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, раз хотите именно функцию с посимвольным перебором, то вот:

```js
const EXCL_SYMBOLS = ' .,'.split('');
var string = "Hallo, World";

function firstWord(str) {
  for (var chr, result = '', i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chr = str.charAt(i);
    if (EXCL_SYMBOLS.includes(chr.toLowerCase()))
      break;
    else
      result += chr;
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(firstWord(string));
```

Такой подход [значительнее медленнее](https://jsperf.com/questions-823853) выбора регулярным выражением.